# Tag merger/synonym suggestions

Tags: support, synonym-request

The following would merge nicely:

Pre-build:

- [pre-buildevent](/questions/tagged/pre-buildevent) (34 questions)
- [pre-build-event](/questions/tagged/pre-build-event) (10 questions)
  and maybe
- [prebuild](/questions/tagged/prebuild) (32 questions)

Post-build:

- [postbuild-event](/questions/tagged/postbuild-event) (99 questions)
- [post-build-event](/questions/tagged/post-build-event) (13 questions)
  and maybe
- [post-build](/questions/tagged/post-build) (27 questions)

For these two I would suggest a common format for their respective main tag, say `[pre|post]-build-event`.

Object-file:

- [object-files](/questions/tagged/object-files) (34 questions)
- [object-file](/questions/tagged/object-file) (19 questions)

Design Patterns:

- [design-pattern](/questions/tagged/design-pattern) (974 questions)
- [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns) (8103 questions)

I don't have the required score in any of them to suggest the synonyms